# Policies not hitting / working in Laravel 9 with Spatie Permission Package 5

Tags: laravel, permissions, policy

Greetings. I'm having difficulties to use Policy Laravel 9. I have tried all day to figuring this out why POLICY class is not hitting by controller /  route but could not find solution that. All possible solutions which I understand already tried.

Here is my code.

**Policy** class:

```
class PacketPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        dd('hit packet create');
    }
}
```

And **controller** class

```
class PacketController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create the controller instance.
     * Also check authorization on route level as per associated policies
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Packet::class, 'packet'); // Option-1 tried. Not working 
    }
    public function create()
    {
        //request()->user()->can('create', Packet::class); // Option-2 tried. Not working 


        return inertia('Packet/Create', [
            'item' => [],
        ]);
    }
}
```

and even register policy classes in **AuthServiceProvider** class like so.

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Packet' => 'App\Policies\PacketPolicy', // Not working
        OutboundOrder::class => OutboundOrderPolicy::class, // Not working either 
    ];
}
```

**Route** is

```
 Route::resource('packet', PacketController::class);
```

Please help me out what i'm missing here. I don't understand why my Policy class not hitting when in visit `domain/packet/create`  route

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also, and It's happened because I put custom permissions on AuthServiceProvider.

I give owner or admin all permission so it'll always return true even without having permissions.

```php
public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $token) {
            return config('app.frontend_url')."/password-reset/$token?email={$notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()}";
        });


        // I comment this part and realize it's work. 
        // except on Owner and Admin, because this custom permission will override my policy
        /* 
        Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
             return $user->hasRole('Owner') || $user->hasRole('Admin') ? true : null;
        });
        */
    }
```

So, maybe you have custom permissions on your AuthServiceProvider too?